# XCode just asking about 3 icons and failing validation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm facing problems with XCode when I need to create the icons of my app. The problem comes from the validation, where it says I haven't referenced the icons properly.

I've tried using the asset catalog and it doesn't work. I've tried also modifying the `info.plist` with `CFBundleIcons` and it doesn't work either, but even more, I've tried creating the app icons, selecting the folder on the *General* tab and it just shows me 3 icons in total to be selected. It still fails validation even after selecting those 3 icons.

See screenshots for details: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Ifb.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVLyR.jpg)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Names like "58p", "29p" don't look valid to me either...

Comment: That's it. I think that -I don't know where- the project is searching for those files, but there are no references at the info.plist, not even the CFBundleIcon (because I've read here various solutions)

Comment: I would remove any references you currently do have in the project and move any images you currently do have to another (temporary) folder then then drag them back into the Xcode Project configuration window and tell it to copy the images.  It *should* do the right thing...

Comment: I've done that already but the problem persists. Where should I find why is the project searching for those "58p" files and so? Seriously, this is blowing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project with cmd + shift + k.
Check if the files are in a valid format (PNG, size) and not corrupted
Check the [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) for the correct sizes

If that doesn't work try this:

1. Clean the project with cmd + shift + k
2. Make a backup on your desktop of the images all the images mentioned
3. Remove the images from the project (all files mentioned by the archiver that cause a problem)
4. Again do a clean (cmd + shift + k)
5. Add the files again and
6. Create a build (cmd + shift + b)
7. Archive

If that doesn't work probably something in your project files became corrupt. You can fix it in the following ways:

- Remove the CFBundleIconFile ("Icon file") parameter from your project's .plist file if it is in there.
- Open the project file in a text editor and remove all the references to the conflicting files. Try archiving. If successful add files again and archive. If the problem persist, there might be something wrong with the images.
- Create a new project, import the files and see if the problem persists. It might be possible something in your project files became corrupt

*src: [Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIconFile": Icon.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166434/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-under-key-cfbundleic)

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I've tried your solution and it doesn't work neither. Same error when trying to archive validation. I'm getting crazy with this...

Comment: All these pointless *Clean the project* answers are like the scripted suggestions you get from call centres when your internet router doesn't work.  "Turn it off and on".  No!

Comment: lol, hope is still free! I'm desperate at this point so everything I can try is a good try :/

Comment: What happens if you remove the images and then archive? Does it archive successfully?

Comment: No, it still crying about those files (and they haven't even been in my project!)

Comment: You can do:
1. Open the project file in a text editor and remove all the references to the conflicting files 2. Create a new project, import the files and see if the problem persists. It might be possible something in your project files became corrupt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but trying for the 9842359834597987th time this finally works. I've deleted the images, cleaned the project and concrete the icons again and again. I don't get what happened but this simply works. Maybe the project became somehow "corrupted"...

Thank you everyone involved into this :)