# Warnings and errors validating iOS app for upload

Tags: ios, validation

When trying to upload an app the following errors occur:

[image]

The images are in the project, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Also I am not sure what the armv7 error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this answer says,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358534/793607) you need to remove the `CFBundleIconFile` ("Icon file") parameter from your project's .plist file.  Also, you need to include armv7 as "Valid Architectures" for both your project and your target.