# ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'"

Tags: xcode

Trying to upload my iOS app, I got this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'"
```

More:

```
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Checksums = {MyApp.ipa=5fd691cb09c481406ad0fa356823baaa}
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'"]
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MinimumFileSizeThresholdForCheckum = 104857600
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FilesToUpload = [metadata.xml, MyApp.ipa]
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'"
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.
[2015-02-24 14:26:04 MEZ] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1




Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/rh/lwg7fq_d68qgkndtzgtzsqv40000gn/T/3CAC8400-1C27-4AFE-914F-068B71C4BA82/969567779.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key '$key': '$path'"
```

What/where is `'$key': '$path'`. Can anybody give me an advice? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean upload your app? Are you trying to submit it to the AppStore?

Comment: Yes, I tried to upload/submit my app via Application Loader. Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to just use Xcode to do this.

First Clean the project. Then archive it. Select iOS Device as the build target then "Project" - "Archive".

Once that is done it will open up the Xcode Organizer screen with your new Archie. Hit "Verify" to check it's ok and then "Submit" and it will upload to iTunes Connect for you.

You have to select the account an app first.

It's a lot easier than any other method I have found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where is "Verify"? I tried "Validate…" and "Submit…" but always the same error. Please help me!

Comment: I meant Validate. Hmm... Are you using Asset Catalogs for all the images? Did you try cleaning the project folder?

Comment: Yes I use Asset Catalogs for all the images. Do you mean Product>Clean? I did.

Comment: Yeah. Try Product and hold ALT. It will change to "Clean Project Folder". TBH it sounds like a file is missing or a file is being referenced that isn't there but not sure where to start looking with that :(

Comment: Did you try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166434/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-under-key-cfbundleic

Comment: I'm trying it. I'll answer in some minutes.

Comment: Still no success. More ideas?

Comment: Not without being able to see what's going on. Sorry

Comment: It works now. Under "Target>App Icons and Launch Images" I changed App Icons Source an Launch Icon Source to "Don't use assents catalogs". Deleted Images.xcassets folder. App Icons Source>Use assents catalogs. Now I created and added all icons again. Result: it works.